# Create Salesforce Case From Slack

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-communities, slack-commands

I am trying to create Salesforce Case from Slack using /service-create case present in Service Setup for slack.

This is the doc link: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.slack_service_create_record.htm&type=5

Can someone please help me with this. Why am I not able to use this command?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: /service-create is not a valid command this is the error I am getting. I am able to use the other commands like /service-create-swarm and all. Except for this /service-create case

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure the [Service Cloud App for Slack](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.slack_app_get.htm&type=5)?

Also, ensure to configure [Salesforce for Slack](https://slack.com/apps/A03269G3DNE-salesforce-for-slack?tab=more_info) app so that your account is linked to your Slack.

Hope this helps and have a blessed one!

Comment: Yes I did. I am able to use all the other commands like /service-create-swarm. I am not able to use the /service-create case command

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).